# What is StackShare, actually?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, email, clone

SE Inc. has sent me this promotional email about StackShare, directing me to this [announcement](https://stackshare.io/posts/announcing-private-stackshare-for-teams-beta).

Well, I read it, but I don't actually understand what this StackShare thing actually does. Is it at all question-and-answer-like, or is it just a different software service by SE Inc.?

(edit:) It seems the email was not actually from SE Inc. - I was just confused to think that it was.

Comment: I doubt that's a Stack Exchange product ...

Comment: Could you share the email you received?

Comment: That announcement did not come from us.

Comment: We are not affiliated with StackShare at all

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: Fair enough, but I'm sure a lot of people will get this false impression - because they never signed up for StackShare emails but are already getting StackOverflow emails recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackShare appears to be a separate company. WHOIS records for `StackShare.io` reference a registering company called "StackShare, Inc." located in California. It looks like StackShare may want to be seen as similar to Stack Exchange - their website look and feel is astonishingly reminiscent of this one.

You may have gotten an email that simply looked similar to an SE email. Check it again, paying careful attention to the company name and the email headers.

Comment: Then why would SE promote it?

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I don't know. The OP probably misread the email.

Answer (score 4):

Just by looking at [StackShare's homepage](https://stackshare.io/), it's a website for companies to collaborate on the products (or tech stacks) they use. At the bottom of their homepage, they describe themselves:

> StackShare provides online software for displaying and sharing your technology stack, which is made up of the software that you use. We're an online community that features comparisons, ratings, reviews, recommendations, and discussions of the best software tools and software infrastructure services.

[Stack Exchange appeared to have used StackShare](https://stackshare.io/companies/stack-exchange) (five years ago at least), but they don't appear to be affiliated.

Answer (score -1):

I read the stackshare site it comes from. I'm not sure I get it either but to me it seems to be like those signature blocks you see people posting on gaming forums boasting about their gaming rigs specs, but this time for company staff to boast about the technology bits they use.

I'm not even sure its anything to do with StackExchange.